# html form that passes information to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

i'm new with Javascript and i'm trying to add a form to my html page that sends the input information to a variable, so I can use that variable later on.. It's a replacement for an input prompt that saves the information to a variable. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: HTML doesn't "send" data to JavaScript.  But JavaScript can inspect HTML elements and get data from them.  Have you made any attempt at this?  A lot of introductory JavaScript tutorials are going to show how to get an HTML element and pull some information from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

I assume you are using a stand input control, and let us assume text... First you will have to put the form in your HTML, so in our JavaScript we can find the input using its the id. We also need a button, a regular button, not a submit button, for the user to click on when he decides to give in his input. We will attach a click event so that when our user clicks our JavaScript starts working So here is a start for our HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="setClick()">
    Submit
</button>
```

Just before you say, "Yeah! I KNOW that!", let us look at the JavaScript side... We need to first get the textbox's value, So that when it is clicked the textbox's `value` property is fetched and inserted into the variable `input`.. So here is the JavaScript:

```
function setClick()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value; 
    //saves the current value of the textbox into the input variable
    alert(input);
}
/*
    So now each time the button is clicked the variable "input" is assigened
    the textbox's value
*/
```

## Complete Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Submit
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setClick()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value; 
    //saves the current value of the textbox into the input variable
    alert(input);
}
    /*
    So now each time the button is clicked the variable "input" is assigened
    the textbox's value
    */
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="submit" onclick="setClick()">
    Submit
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No prob ;). I felt just like you when I was still learning JavaScript, and googling didn't work; I didn't know *what* to search for!